# Running and Playing GNUChess in Python with this code... that runs forever

Tags: python

I want to use this code for my own project where I have a touchscreen interface (coded through python) enter commands while the gnuchess program runs as a subprocess. Problem is, when I try to run the code below, it doesn't wait for my input for a chess move, it just keeps running scrolling infinitely down and I can't input anything! I kill the program, try to fix it so I can input my move, and run it again, but it always just scrolls infinitely. I am very beginner-level at programming, so if anyone can explain what is happening and how I can fix it so that I may play gnuchess through python and then integrate it with my touchscreen gui, I will be very grateful. Thank you!

As I mentioned I am quite low-level when it comes to programming, so I had to borrow this code that I don't fully grasp, though I know it does what I want it to do.  Almost.  I try to edit it, but I don't really know how.

```
import subprocess

gnuchess = subprocess.Popen('gnuchess', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout 
= subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

# Python 3 strings are Unicode and must be encoded before writing to a 
# pipe (and decoded after reading)
gnuchess.stdin.write('e4\n'.encode())

while True:   
    L = gnuchess.stdout.readline().decode()
    L = L[0:-1]
    print(L)
    if L.startswith('My move is'):
        movimiento = L.split()[-1]
        break

print(movimiento)

gnuchess.stdin.write('exit\n'.encode())

gnuchess.terminate()
```

I expect to be able to input a move, but instead the program, when run, becomes a runaway train and just scrolls indefinitely without being able to engage with the program.

Comment: Perhaps use `asyncio`. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) use `data = await proc.stdout.readline()`

Comment: when I run on Linux Mint 19.2 then it doesn't scroll. It looks like it works correctly. But there is different problem - when it asks for move `White (1):` then there is no `"\n"`at the end and code can't read it with `readline()`. `readline()` blocks all code because it is waiting for `"\n"` to return full line. You would have to read char by char - with `stdout.read(1)` - concatenate chars and check: if last char is `"\n"` then display it, if there is `White (1) :` then you can send move.

Comment: check also [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which runs external process and may check strings in stdout - so it does something similar to your code

Answer (score 1):

When I run on Linux Mint 19.2 then it doesn't scroll. It looks like it works correctly.

But there is different problem - when it asks for move `White (1) :` then there is no `"\n"` at the end of line and you can't read it with `readline()`. `readline()` blocks all code because it is waiting for `"\n"` to return full line. You would have to read char by char - with `stdout.read(1)` - concatenate chars and check: if last char is `"\n"` then display it, if there is `White (1) :` then you can send move.

```
import subprocess
import re

p = subprocess.Popen('gnuchess', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

line = ''

try:

    while True:
        #print('wait>')
        char = p.stdout.read(1).decode()
        #print('char>', char)
        line += char
        if char == '\n':
            if re.match('My move is : (.*)\n', line):
                print(line)
                break

            print(line, end='')
            line = ''

        if re.match('White \(.*\) : ', line):
            print(line, end='')

            print('e4\n', end='')
            p.stdin.write('e4\n'.encode())
            p.stdin.flush() # inform buffer to send it 

            line = ''

    p.stdin.write('exit\n'.encode())

    p.terminate()

except KeyboardInterrupt as ex:
    print('Killing process')
    p.terminate()
```

---

You can also try to use [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

I didn't use `pexpect` before but I made this example which

```
import pexpect

try:
    p = pexpect.spawn('gnuchess')

    print('--- white ---')
    p.expect('White (.*) :')
    print(p.before.decode())
    print(p.after.decode())
    p.sendline('e4')

    print('--- black ---')
    p.expect('My move is : (.*)\n')
    print(p.before.decode())
    print(p.after.decode())
    computer_move = p.match.groups()
    print("computer's move:", computer_move[0].decode())

    print('--- white ---')
    print(p.before.decode())
    print(p.after.decode())
    p.sendline('a4')

    print('--- black ---')
    p.expect('My move is : (.*)\n')
    print(p.before.decode())
    print(p.after.decode())
    computer_move = p.match.groups()
    print("computer's move:", computer_move[0].decode())

    print('--- exit ---')
    p.sendline('exit')

except KeyboardInterrupt as ex:
    print('Killing process')
    p.kill(9)
```

[pexpect examples](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html)